# NGINX to reverse proxy websockets AND enable SSL (wss://)?

Tags: ssl, tcp, proxy, nginx, mod-proxy

I'm so lost and new to building NGINX on my own but I want to be able to enable secure websockets without having an additional layer.

I don't want to enable SSL on the websocket server itself but instead I want to use NGINX to add an SSL layer to the whole thing.

Every web page out there says I can't do it, but I know I can! Thanks to whoever (myself) can show me how!

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Just to note that nginx has now support for Websockets on the release 1.3.13. Example of use:

```
location /websocket/ {

    proxy_pass ​http://backend_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;

}
```

You can also check the [nginx changelog](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES) and the [WebSocket proxying](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) documentation.

Comment: It has the same timeout issues as expressed above ;)

Comment: @3rdEden: For timeout issues, `proxy_read_timeout` works, I edited the answer.

Comment: Where should I put this configuration and what is backend_host ?

Comment: @Sekai: A `location` directive is put within a `server` or another `location` directive (see [location docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)). `backend_host` is an `upstream` (see [upstream docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream)) - one or a group of servers that you'll proxy to.

Comment: @RadkoDinev -- is upstream necessary, or if I just have one server, I can just use that in the proxy_pass directive?

Comment: @jlee As stated in the [documentation of the `proxy_pass` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) it's value is an URL in general. Having one server, you could just use it's DNS name or IP address as a value. `upstream` is usually used for more than one server, and/or when you want to specify additional options (e.g. [`keepalive`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive)).

Comment: What about this timeout problem? Do we have really to set it to a very large number to avoid it? Isn't there now any more elegant solution?

Comment: Have you figured out the solution? Since I had to also faced a similar problem
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/53411060/7713811

Comment: Worked for me. I ran into this problem when deploying a Blazor Server app to Azure Container Instances after following this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl

Comment: If we're using https why are we writing `"proxy_http_version"` and `"proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade"`?

Comment: Trying hard for weeks without any working solutions :-( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593975/esp32-websocket-or-socketio-to-node-red-throught-nginx-ssl

Comment: Note that this must be placed inside a location {} context, as shown in the example. Placing this snippet into the server {} context did not work for me.

Answer (score 93):

This worked for me:

```
location / {
    # redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost:8080
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # WebSocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

-- borrowed from: https://github.com/nicokaiser/nginx-websocket-proxy/blob/df67cd92f71bfcb513b343beaa89cb33ab09fb05/simple-wss.conf

Comment: I had trouble getting TeamCity's web sockets to work behind my reverse proxy.  Your `# WebSocket support` snipped did it for me. I was previously trying to forward port 400, however wss works over 443. FYI future readers :)

Comment: Have you figured out the solution? Since I had to also faced a similar problem
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/53411060/7713811

Comment: I like this answer the best, as many people (like yourself) use / for both websockets and regular HTTP2.

Comment: @Anyone what would be the calling Javascript?

Comment: This worked for me and ShinobiCCTV via unraid and reverse proxy. I could see web sockets getting blocked.

Comment: When I develop by using the package ```python-socketio```,  
tt works. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 59):

Have no fear, because a brave group of Ops Programmers have solved the situation with a brand spanking new **[nginx_tcp_proxy_module](https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module)**

Written in August 2012, so if you are from the future you should do your homework.

### Prerequisites

Assumes you are using CentOS:

- Remove current instance of NGINX (suggest using dev server for this)
- If possible, save your old NGINX config files so you can re-use them (that includes your `init.d/nginx` script)
- `yum install pcre pcre-devel openssl openssl-devel` and any other necessary libs for building NGINX
- Get the **nginx_tcp_proxy_module** from GitHub here https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module and remember the folder where you placed it (make sure it is not zipped)

### Build Your New NGINX

Again, assumes CentOS:

- `cd /usr/local/`
- `wget 'http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.2.1.tar.gz'`
- `tar -xzvf nginx-1.2.1.tar.gz`
- `cd nginx-1.2.1/`
- `patch -p1 < /path/to/nginx_tcp_proxy_module/tcp.patch`
- `./configure --add-module=/path/to/nginx_tcp_proxy_module --with-http_ssl_module` (you can add more modules if you need them)
- `make`
- `make install`

Optional:

- `sudo /sbin/chkconfig nginx on`

### Set Up Nginx

Remember to copy over your old configuration files first if you want to re-use them.

**Important:** you will need to create a `tcp {}` directive at the highest level in your conf. *Make sure it is not inside your `http {}` directive.*

The example config below shows a single upstream websocket server, and two proxies for both SSL and Non-SSL.

```
tcp {
    upstream websockets {
        ## webbit websocket server in background
        server 127.0.0.1:5501;
        
        ## server 127.0.0.1:5502; ## add another server if you like!

        check interval=3000 rise=2 fall=5 timeout=1000;
    }   

    server {
        server_name _;
        listen 7070;

        timeout 43200000;
        websocket_connect_timeout 43200000;
        proxy_connect_timeout 43200000;

        so_keepalive on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

        websocket_pass websockets;
        websocket_buffer 1k;
    }

    server {
        server_name _;
        listen 7080;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate      /path/to/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/key.key;

        timeout 43200000;
        websocket_connect_timeout 43200000;
        proxy_connect_timeout 43200000;

        so_keepalive on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

        websocket_pass websockets;
        websocket_buffer 1k;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was pretty helpful, but I was still getting timeouts at 60secs.  I managed to fix this by setting the following:

  timeout 43200000;
  websocket_connect_timeout 43200000;
  websocket_read_timeout 43200000;
  websocket_send_timeout 43200000;
  proxy_connect_timeout 43200000;
  proxy_read_timeout 43200000;
  proxy_send_timeout 43200000;

Comment: I wanted to serve websockets off the same http port and only after the browser had been authenticated.  It looks like this can't handle websockets on the same port.  How do people handle this?

Comment: It will take some software modification to detect the incoming protocol. Since websockets actually start as an HTTP handshake (a higher software level than TCP) you have to tweak your app to handle both TCP and HTTP traffic. I can't recommend a way to do this just yet.

Comment: In case other folks from 2018 come here, these directives don't work any more. Go to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html for recent instructions or see Harlan T Wood's answer below.

Comment: Have you figured out the solution? Since I had to also faced a similar problem
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/53411060/7713811

Answer (score 26):

for .net core 2.0 Nginx with SSL

```
location / {
    # redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost:8080
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # WebSocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
}
```

This worked for me

Comment: what is the c# code. I have currently this in for windows/iis _server = new WebSocketServer("wss://0.0.0.0:8200/MessageRelayer")
{
    Certificate = new X509Certificate2(PfxFileName, SslPassword),
    RestartAfterListenError = true
};

Comment: I'm using SignalR

Answer (score 14):

For me, it came down to the `proxy_pass` location setting. I needed to change over to using the HTTPS protocol, and have a valid SSL certificate set up on the node server side of things. That way when I introduce an external node server, I only have to change the IP and everything else remains the same config.

I hope this helps someone along the way... I was staring at the problem the whole time... sigh...

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
upstream nodeserver {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 default_server ssl http2 ipv6only=on;
        server_name mysite.com;
        ssl_certificate ssl/site.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key ssl/site.key;
        location /websocket { #replace /websocket with the path required by your application
                proxy_pass https://nodeserver;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_intercept_errors on;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            }
}
```

Comment: I tried `localtion /horizon`, but it's not working. Only `localtion /` or `location /websockify` works.   Don't know why...

Comment: works if replace "proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;" with "proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;"

Answer (score 11):

Using nginx/1.14.0

i have a websocket-server running on port 8097 and users connect from to wss on port 8098, nginx just decrypts the content and forwards it to the websocket server

So i have this config file (in my case `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`)

```
server {
    listen   8098;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/domain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /root/domain.key;
    location / {

        proxy_pass http://hostname:8097;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

    }
}
```

Comment: In 2022 this helped me a lot. Nothing worked for WSS/WS until I added the read timeout.

Answer (score 10):

A good, concise article by Pankaj Malhotra discusses how to do this with NGINX and is available [here](http://pankajmalhotra.com/Websockets-SSL-TLS-Termination-Using-NGINX-Proxy).

The basic NGINX configuration is reproduced below:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream appserver {
    server 192.168.100.10:9222; # appserver_ip:ws_port
}

server {
    listen 8888; // client_wss_port

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://appserver;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the modern versions of NGINX also address the timeout issues?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add SSL in your test environment, then you can use `mkcert`. Below I mentioned the GitHub URL. 
https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert 
And also below I mentioned sample nginx configuration for reverse proxy.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name test.local;
        return 301 https://test.local$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name test.local;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/test.local.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/test.local-key.pem;

   location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Client-Verify SUCCESS;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```