# Websocket PHP server using SSL (WSS)

Tags: php, ssl, encryption, websocket

I'm asking because I'm in dead end with my `PHP` websocket server. I'm looking for a solution for 2 weeks and I visited all results in `Google` with tags: `websocket`, `SSL`, `WSS`.

The problem is caused by using `WSS` `(websocket secure)`, my server works perfect with `WS`. But I have to use `SSL`, I can't give up this. More precisely, when client (browser) sends handshake to server, it is encrypted. I think so, because it is a mix of really strange chars. Next, I thought I should decrypt this string with `openssl_*` functions, so I wrote a code:

```
//$pKey - decrypted private key of my SSL certificate
//$buffer - string with strange chars - probably encrypted handshake
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($pKey);
openssl_private_decrypt($buffer , $open , $privateKey);
openssl_free_key($privateKey);
```

And I get errors:

```
error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01
```

or

```
error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed
```

Of cause `$open` is null. I tried with each padding option and errors were the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your web server should already be decrypting everything for you.

Comment: But it isn't and helpdesk/support of my host service said it is normal and I have to decrypt it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a separate process (Nginx/STunnel) handle SSL.

See
[NGINX to reverse proxy websockets AND enable SSL (wss://)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102110/nginx-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-and-enable-ssl-wss)