# Ngnix to support ssl encryption in websocket

Tags: ssl, websocket

I have searched all over the internet but didn't find any suitable solution (not a hack). As I said, I need to add ssl to websockets.

I found this question:
[NGINX to reverse proxy websockets AND enable SSL (wss://)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102110/nginx-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-and-enable-ssl-wss)

crockpotveggies suggested to add tcp module, but I don't think it's a good one (it's old and third party).

Does anyone came across this? Thanks.

Comment: And why doesn't the most up-voted answer work?

Comment: Because it's not a solution. The other answer uses 3rd party library and I don't want to use it. I'll update the question when I find the solution.