# NGINX as a WebSocket Proxy with Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, websocket

I have an application that uses WebSocket on port 8080. wss://aws1.orotechnologies.com.au:8080

The application is running inside a Docker container. Nginx is the web server. All HTTP is redirected to HTTPS.

```
sudo docker ps
 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 
 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 
 0.0.0.0:3088->3088/tcp, 
 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

How do I configure Nginx to serve WebSocket connections?

I did read these materials. But I am still not sure how to configure Nginx. My port 8080 is already used. Should I change the docker port settings and have a Nginx server to listen on 8080?

- [NGINX to reverse proxy websockets AND enable SSL (wss://)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102110/nginx-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-and-enable-ssl-wss)
- https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Comment: did you found solution to it?

Comment: It was not the docker issue. I was configuring orocommerce. The problem was with the oro configuration.

Comment: thank you for the response, in my case it was AWS ELB problem with reverse proxy.