# Secure WebSocket Proxy for Unsecured WebSocket Server

Tags: security, websocket

I have a server (that I don't control, but on my network) that uses unsecured web sockets to communicate. Rather than allow communication directly with that server from outside the network, I'm wanting to set up a secure proxy that uses secured web sockets to receive the requests from outside the network, and then forward those on to the real server within the network. That way, the unsecure traffic never leaves the network and any communication with outside the network is done via the secured proxy.

What would be the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Try nginx proxy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102110/nginx-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-and-enable-ssl-wss

Comment: https://github.com/nicokaiser/nginx-websocket-proxy/blob/master/simple-wss.conf

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about having the internal communication still over regular HTTP, but only have communication to the external world over HTTPS, then this is a common practice. HAProxy supports this, and the general term is called "Terminating SSL" or "Terminating TLS".

You can read more about it here: [TLS termination proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy)