# Websocket connection to 'wss://mydomain/hub' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a asp.net core app with signalR, working perfectly on development machine and iis too. but when I published to nginx(reverse-proxy) throws an error: `failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`. I found that websocket works better on ssl so I installed self-signed ssl, still problem remains the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to configure Nginx to proxy websocket connections, it does not handle websocket connections by default. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html and [NGINX to reverse proxy websockets AND enable SSL (wss://)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102110/nginx-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-and-enable-ssl-wss) for further information about enabling websockets for Nginx.