# how to setup daphne with nginx with djnago channels for websockets

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, django-channels, daphne

I have to set up the Django server with WebSockets and HTTP requests. It works fine in my local system. and also on the server without SSL, but when we use the SSL on the server the HTTP request works fine on the `https` but WebSocket does not work with `wss`

I am using Nginx for the webserver and daphne.

this is my Nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.name;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /root/myprojectdir/staff_hiring/static;
    }

        location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /root/myprojectdir/staff_hiring/media;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

and this is my asgi file

```
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import staff_admin.routing
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'staff_hiring.settings')

django.setup()
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "https": get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket':AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
          staff_admin.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
    ) 
        )
    )
})
```

and routing file

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
  re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()), # Using asgi
  # url(r'/ws/chat/', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi())

]
```

Comment: this answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102110/nginx-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-and-enable-ssl-wss