# ESP32 WebSocket or SocketIO to Node-RED throught NGINX & SSL

Tags: nginx, websocket, socket.io, esp32, nginx-reverse-proxy

### Setup

- Client 1 : a WebPage with SocketIO requesting the server
- Client 2 : an [ESP32](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/33050639690.html) with [Links2004/arduinoWebSockets](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets)
- Server   : Ubuntu / NGINX redirecting to a Node-RED

### Problem

**OK** : WebPage connect to The server and receive messages

```
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=***&sid=******* HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "https://path/to/server" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

**KO** : The ESP32 send the request but do not get any response

```
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling HTTP/1.1" 200 118 "-" "arduino-WebSocket-Client"
```

There is also an error on the Arduino/PlatformIO side :

```
[122264][E][WiFiClient.cpp:517] flush(): fail on fd 48, errno: 11, "No more processes"
[WSc] Disconnected!
```

What I understand is

- both clients correctly received the 200 code
- the esp32 do not provice referer but I don't think it is required ?
- the esp32 has flush/fd error but it could be related to the server response ?
- If I use websocket instead od socketio I have the same error fd error th accesslog

  "GET /ws/path HTTP/1.1" 101 0 "-" "arduino-WebSocket-Client"

On Node-RED the node keep connect/disconnect that mean it receive the request and the error could be on ESP32 side again:

[image: websocket node-red]

Basic HTTP Request works. It will be my workaround (using pulling) if I don't find the bug

EDIT : [See comment on the library](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets/issues/830)

### Code

I follow [the documentation of the library](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets).
The code setup()

```
WiFiClient client;
webSocket.beginSocketIO("path.to.server", 80, "/socket.io/?EIO=4");
//webSocket.begin("path.to.server", 80, "/ws/path");
webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
webSocket.setReconnectInterval(5000);
```

The code loop()

```
webSocket.loop();
```

If I set port 443 instead of 80 I got a 400 error. So may be an issue with NGINX but anyway it should works "without" SSL since 80 is also available.

```
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "arduino-WebSocket-Client"
```

### NGINX

I follow many tutotials and anyway it works with web browser

```
upstream websocket {
  server 127.0.0.1:1880;
}

server {
    #only ports 80 and 443 are open
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    #server name
    server_name path.to.server;

    #LetsEncrypt
    location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    #serve SSL certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/path.to.server/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/path.to.server/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:128m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {

        #redirect any request on http to https
        if ($scheme = http) {
          #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }

        # pass https requests to node-red
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1880;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect  off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        # Proxy Header for websocket
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # Handle cache of static content
        expires $expires;
        add_header Cache-Control $control;
    }
}
```

Comment: But... WebSocket and Socket.IO are not the same thing. Socket.IO starts with a long-polling connection and then tries to upgrade it to a WebSocket if possible. If you are using Socket.IO on your server and the WebSocket library on the ESP32, they might not be able to communicate correctly, because the ESP32 is not implementing the Socket.IO protocol.

Comment: I tried both on both sides : SocketIO on Node-RED and the library cofigured for SocketIO. WebSocket only with Websocket on NodeRED. It works from a webpage not from ESP32

Comment: From an HTTP request, the WS:// upgrade request returns 101 correctly while using the Websocket server, your client needs to reconnect to ws:// like any modern browser would. So your client implementation is lacking that.